# Apply Angular Controller to a Template

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I'm not sure what it is I'm asking, but I want to achieve this:

Index.html:

```
<div ng-view>

</div>
<script>
    angular.module('myApp', ['ngRoute'])
    .config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/', { controller: "HomeController", templateUrl: '/Partials/Home/Dashboard.html' });

        $routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);
</script>
```

Home/Dashboard.html:

```
<h2 class="page-header">{{welcome}}</h2>

<!-- Insert my reusable component here -->
```

My reusable component would reside in `MyComponent/Component.html` and have the controller `myApp.component.controller` associated with it.

So effectively I want to drop in the resuable component into the page and bind it to my controller. So I got as far as having this:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {

      },
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

So how do I now bind my controller to it? Do I do this:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      resolve: function () {
        return /* resolve myApp.component.controller */;
      },
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I just want to clarify a few things up here.

*/MyComponent/Component.html*:

```
<h2>{{welcome}}</h2>
```

*/mycomponent.directive.js*:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller : 'ComponentController',
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

the above bound like this in *index.html*:

```
<h2>{{welcome}}</h2> <!-- this is from ng-controller = HomeController -->

<my-component></my-component> <!-- this is scoping from ng-controller = ComponentController -->
```

This generates the result

```
<h2>Hello from MyComponent</h2>
<h2>Hello from MyComponent</h2>
```

It appears that the `ComponentController` has taken over the entire scope. I then changed the directive to this:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      // controller : 'ComponentController',
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

And changed the *index.html* to this:

```
<h2>{{welcome}}</h2> <!-- this is from ng-controller = HomeController -->

<div ng-controller="ComponentController">
    <my-component></my-component> <!-- this is scoping from ng-controller = ComponentController -->
</div>
```

This gave the correct output:

```
<h2>Welcome from HomeController</h2>
<h2>Welcome from ComponentController</h2>
```

Then I changed the directive again to this:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A', // <----- note this small change, restrict to attributes
      // controller : 'ComponentController',
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

I changed *index.html* to this:

```
<h2>{{welcome}}</h2>
<div ng-controller="ComponentController" my-component></div>
```

And this also produced the desired output, just in less lines of code.

So I just hope this clarifies directives to people a bit better. I put this on for completeness and the steps that I took to achieve this. Obviously I had some help from the other answers which pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: This is a potential problem. Inside the div HomeController is inaccessible.

Comment: In my case I don't need `HomeController` accessible inside the div, in fact that is probably essential!

Answer (score 1):

When a directive requires a controller, it receives that controller as the fourth argument of its 
link function.

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller: 'MyController', // attach it.
      require: ['MyController','^ngModel'],    // required in link function
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs, controllers) {
         var MyController = controllers[0];
         var ngModelCtlr = controllers[1];
         ///...
      }
    };
  });
```

The ^ prefix means that this directive searches for the controller on its parents (without the ^ prefix, the directive would look for the controller on just its own element).

Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.

Comment: I would like to point out that if you use `restrict: 'E'` it means you have to use an element `<my-component></my-component>`

Comment: Take the restriction of your example but no matter. This related to the markup.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign controllers to directives:

```
.directive('MyComponent', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      controller : 'HomeController',
      templateUrl: '/MyComponent/Component.html'
    };
  });
```

Comment: which is better to do, this one, or the other answer